# Python Tkinter Submenu Radio Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, submenu

I am having issues with creating a menu that suits the needs of my application. I am creating an app that requires the user to choose possible items to compare inside of a source menu.

Right now my menu organization is indended to look something like

```
FILE | EDIT | OPTIONS | SOURCE | HELP
```

My issue is, the number of choices inside source is quite large (~100) and needs to be navicable quickly (<5 seconds) or the target audience of my application will probably not use it.

The solution I have in mind is to nest options underneath the data structures they come from. Effectively this means I can treat the Source options and suboptions as two lists:

```
["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"]
```

and

```
[["Option1_1", "Option1_2", "Option1_3"],
["Option2_1","Option2_2","Option2_3"],
["Option3_1","Option3_2","Option3_3"]]
```

I have searched extensively and can't find how to create submenus effectively in Tkinter. When I get a submenu of radiobuttons (checkbuttons would also work), the button click does not activate the command, and that is not a viable solution.

What I would like to do is create a menu that looks something like

```
FILE | SOURCE | ETC...
          Data1    |
               Option1_1
               Option1_2
               Option1_3
         Data2    |
         Data3
```

How can I do this? Preferably while also storing buttons to a list, then appending them to the menu, so that I can call select and deselect if I need to? Radiobuttons or checkbuttons would work, checkbuttons are preferred provided I still have access to them after creation.

Thank you

Here's one example of non-working code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.makeMenu(master)

    def makeMenu(self, parent):
        menuBar = Frame(parent, relief = 'raised', borderwidth = 1)
        fileMenu = Menubutton(menuBar, text = "File")
        fileMenu.pack(side = 'left')
        fileMenu.menu = Menu(fileMenu, tearoff = 0)
        load = Menubutton(fileMenu.menu, text="Load")
        load.pack(anchor=W)
        source = Menubutton(fileMenu.menu, text="Source")
        source.pack(anchor=W)
        source.menu = Menu(source, tearoff = 0)
        self._listi = ["who", "what", "where", "how"]
        self._buttonList = []
        for l in self._listi:
            c = Checkbutton(master = source.menu, text=l, command=lambda arg0=l: self.test(arg0))
            self._buttonList.append([l, c])
            c.pack()
        save = Button(master=fileMenu.menu, text="Save")
        save.pack(anchor=W)
        exit = Button(master=fileMenu.menu, text="Exit", command = self.quit)
        exit.pack()
        fileMenu['menu'] = fileMenu.menu
        menuBar.pack()

    def test(self, arg0):
        for b in self._buttonList:
            if arg0 != b[0]:
                b[1].deselect()
            elif arg0 == b[0]:
                b[1].select()


# create app
myApp = App()

# start program
myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is nothing particularly hard about creating submenus, assuming you know how to make menus. Show us what you've tried and perhaps we can point out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Okay. I have added one example of nonworking code. I really just need an example of how to do this and can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add `Checkbutton` or `Button` instances to a menu. You must use the `add_checkbutton` or `add_radiobutton` or `add_command` methods.  Also, you don't need to create a menubar from a frame and menubuttons -- you can attach a menu directly to a window. Also, you don't need to programatically select or deselect the checkbuttons or radiobuttons, that is taken care of by tkinter.

I've modified your code to illustrate:

```
from Tkinter import *
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.makeMenu(master)

    def makeMenu(self, parent):
        menuBar = Menu(parent)
        parent.configure(menu=menuBar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menuBar)
        sourceMenu = Menu(menuBar)
        menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Load")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label="Source", menu=sourceMenu)
        self._listi = ["who","what","where","how"]
        for l in self._listi:
            sourceMenu.add_checkbutton(label=l, command=lambda arg0=l: self.test(arg0))
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save")
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)


    def test(self, arg0):
        print "you clicked on", arg0


# create app
root = Tk()
myApp = App(root)

# start program
myApp.mainloop()
```

Note that I also added a line of code to create the root window, and I pass that root window into the constructor for the app.